# Android 13 : Incorrect long press visualization effect for bordered button

Tags: android

I am using the following selector, to create a bordered button with correct short press/ long press UI visualization effect.

### drawable/button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#ff9f9f9f">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <corners android:radius="24dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button" />

</ripple>
```

### drawable/button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ff9f9f9f"/>

    <corners android:radius="24dp" />
</shape>
```

### layout/activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"

        android:id="@+id/save_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Here's the the short press effect, in both Android API 33 and API 27

### Short press effect in Android API 33 and API 27 (OK)

[image]

---

### Long press effect in Android API 27 (OK)

[image]

However, the long press effect does not look good in API 33. The long press effect is not retained, even the user hold down his finger on the screen.

---

### Long press effect in Android API 33 (NOT OK)

[image]

---

May I know, how I can fix the long press effect of bordered button in Android API 33?

Here is the demo project for your testing purpose : https://github.com/yccheok/bordered-button-long-press-issue